# Formatar palavra caso esteja em um datatable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Dado meu datatable:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem a palavra ***Atack***. É possível criar uma verificação que caso esta palavra esteja no datatable ela receba uma formatação diferente? Ex: Fique em negrito e a cor seja Azul.

Comment: A palavra atack que você quer estilizar ela aparece somente na coluna "Aumenta" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que você pode criar um style desta forma:

 `.atack {
    background-image: none !important;
    color: blue !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%!imporant;
    height: 100%!imporant;
}`

E no outputText que vc quer modificar coloca a verificação:

`styleClass="#{valor.toLowerCase().indexOf('atack')!= -1 ? 'atack':''}"`

Caso você queria modificar apenas a palavra `atack`, poderia então criar um método no `beam` e verificar se no valor contem a palavra, não se seria uma **boa prática** fazer desta forma:


  `public String contemAtack(String val) {
   //remova os espaços entre < b e < f e < /font e < /b
    return val.replace("Atack", < b>< font color=#0080c0>Atack< /font>< /b>);
  }`
 
E no datatable adicionaria a verificação nas colunas desejadas:

`< h:outputText value="#{seuBeam.contemAtack(valor)}" escape="false" />`

Comment: Sua primeira sugestão foi ótima, porém tenho mais palavras pra formatar com diferentes formatações. O que você me indicaria?

Comment: O que significa o -1 na condição ?

Comment: é o index, ou seja, se ele for diferente de -1 então a palavra contem na string